# How to get a list of areas or devices in my home assistant via API

Tags: zigbee, home-automation, home-assistant

I have checked the home assistant documentation page for API's. I could not get and endpoint that would return a list of created areas(kitchen, living room etc) or a list of all my devices.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Theres these threads about adding support to expose available areas via rest api here: 
https://community.home-assistant.io/t/how-to-get-list-of-areas-through-websocket-api-or-hass-object/426485
https://community.home-assistant.io/t/get-api-areas-rest-endpoint/271440

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the REST `/api/template` endpoint:

```bash
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer abc123' '<instance url>/api/template' -d '{"template": "{{ areas() }}"}'
```

Be sure to check out the [REST API documentation](https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/api/rest), particularly on how to get the bearer token. You may find the [templating documentation](https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/configuration/templating/) useful as well.